# How can i split an image in to multiple parts?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, image-manipulation, uiimage

Can any body explain me how an image can be (equally and unequally) split in to multiple parts in iPhone OS. It is very helpful to me if you provide sample code.

Answer (score 7):

I have adapted some code I got out of [Bill Dudney](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/)'s [Core Animation Book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bdcora) to accomplish this task:

```
- (NSArray*)splitImageIntoRects:(CGImageRef)anImage{

    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(anImage), CGImageGetHeight(anImage));

    NSMutableArray *splitLayers = [NSMutableArray array];

            kXSlices = 3;
            kYSlices = 3;        

    for(int x = 0;x < kXSlices;x++) {
        for(int y = 0;y < kYSlices;y++) {
            CGRect frame = CGRectMake((imageSize.width / kXSlices) * x,
                                     (imageSize.height / kYSlices) * y,
                                     (imageSize.width / kXSlices),
                                     (imageSize.height / kYSlices));

            CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
            layer.frame = frame;                                                    
            CGImageRef subimage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(drawnImage, frame);
            layer.contents = (id)subimage;
            CFRelease(subimage);
            [splitLayers addObject:layer];
        }
    }
    return splitLayers; 
}
```

Note: To get an CGImageRef:

```
CGImageRef anImage = [myUIImage CGImage];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a region defined by an `NSRect` then [this code](http://www.mail-archive.com/discuss-gnustep@gnu.org/msg01291.html) should do it. If you need more complex regions (non-rectangular) then Apple's [Cropped Image example](http://developer.apple.com/SampleCode/Cropped_Image/index.html) includes code for cropping to a Bezier curve (see `-croppedImage` in CroppingImageView.m).